# Any quick way to get a y(x) that satisfies g(y(x))=f(x)?

Tags: numerics

I have two different functions `f(x)` and `g(y)`. Is there a quick way to create some numerical function `y(x)` such that `g(y(x))=f(x)`?
Because the only thing I can think of is giving values `xi` to `x` and saving them in a list along with the solutions of `FindRoot[g(y)==f(xi),y]`.

Comment: `InverseFunction[g]@*f@x`  for monotonic function `g`

Comment: $y(x)=x$ satisfies $g(y(x))=f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]
g[x_] := x^2

Solve[g[y] == f[x], y]
```

---

```
{{y -> -Sqrt[Sin[x]]}, {y -> Sqrt[Sin[x]]}}
```

It depends on the `g` function, if `g` does not have simple inverse then `Solve` can not solve it and you need to use numerical methods.

Comment: the functions i am using have very complicated forms, i was hoping for someway mathematica can give me an interpolated function like it does when using NDSolve

Answer (score 1):

You might use `NDSolve` at least for some section of the curve. Here is an example similar to, but slightly more complicated than, the one shown in a separate response from @azerbajdzan.

```
f[x_] := 5*Sin[x^3 + Cos[x]]
g[x_] := x^2 + Exp[-x]
```

The idea is to equate derivatives of `f[x]` and `g[y[x]]` and also give a suitable starting point, which we can find using `NSolveValues`.

```
nsoln = NDSolveValue[{D[g[y[x]], x] == D[f[x], x], 
    y[0] == First[NSolveValues[{g[y] == f[0], -5 <= y <= 5}, y]]}, 
   y[x], {x, 0, 2}];

(* NDSolveValue::ndsz: At x == 1.412419273342305`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. *)
```

So we only get a partial solution on our requested range. We check that this is a valid solution on the claimed range though.

```
Show[{ListPlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 1.4, .04}]], 
  Plot[g[nsoln], {x, 0, 1.4}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `FunctionInterpolation`:

```
f = Function[x, 5*Sinh[x^3 + Cos[x]]]
g = Function[x, x^2 + Exp[-x]]
y = InverseFunction[g] @* f

yint = FunctionInterpolation[y[x], {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[{g[yint[x]], f[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Of course, it will be a bit of trial and error to find a domain for `y` where you can create the interpolation. If the result is not accurate enough, you often get better results by playing with the `InterpolationPoints` option. The default value of 11 usually isn't high enough.